# Blogger API not retrieving all the post from a blog

Tags: html, google-maps, blogger, blogspot

I have a travel blog with blogspot. I have a page which displays a map of the world with the path taken so far. To do this, I use the blogger API to retrieve the location of each post as follow:

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?callback=handleResponse&amp;key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU">
```

My issue is that it seems that only the last posts are retrieved and the first ones ignored. On the following link, the complete path should contain all the south of Argentina and be linked to the current path shown.

http://el-gato-lindo.blogspot.com/p/map.html

The complete code to generate the map is as follow:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="content">
</div>
<div align="center" id="googleMap" style="height: 900px; width: 620px;">
</div>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&amp;sensor=false">
</script>

<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
var Lat = new Array();
var Lng = new Array();
var Place = new Array();
var TitlePost = new Array();
var UrlPost = new Array();
var DatePost = new Array();

// Get latitude/longitude from Blogger
function handleResponse(response) {
 for(i=0; i< response.items.length; i++){
  if(response.items[i].location != undefined){
   Lat.push(response.items[i].location.lat);
   Lng.push(response.items[i].location.lng);
   Place.push(response.items[i].location.name);
   TitlePost.push(response.items[i].title);
   UrlPost.push(response.items[i].url);
   DatePost.push(response.items[i].published);
  }
 }
}

// Distance btw two places in km
function calcDistance(p1, p2){
 return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(p1,p2)/1000).toFixed(2);
}

// Name of months for date formatting
var m_names = new Array();
m_names.push("January"); 
m_names.push("February"); 
m_names.push("March"); 
m_names.push("April"); 
m_names.push("May"); 
m_names.push("June"); 
m_names.push("July"); 
m_names.push("August"); 
m_names.push("September"); 
m_names.push("October"); 
m_names.push("November"); 
m_names.push("December");

// Create the map based on locations retrieved from Blogger
function initialize(){
 // Get all latitude and longitude
 var pos = new Array();

 // Get the path
 for(var i=0; i<Lat.length; i++){
  pos[i]=new google.maps.LatLng(Lat[i],Lng[i]);
 }

 // Get the last position
 var lastpos=new google.maps.LatLng(Lat[0],Lng[0]);

 // Create the map
 var mapProp = {
  center:lastpos,
  zoom:4,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
  navigationControl:true, 
  streetViewControl:false
  };

 var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

 // Create the path
 var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path:pos,
  strokeColor:"#EE0000",
  strokeOpacity:0.6,
  strokeWeight:7,
  clickable:false,
  map:map
 });

 // Create invisible marker at each destination
 var markerPos = new Array();
 var infowindow = null;

 for(var i=0; i<pos.length; i++){
  marker=new google.maps.Marker({
   position:pos[i],
   icon: {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
    scale:5,
    fillOpacity:0,
    strokeOpacity:0
   },
   clickable:true,
   map:map
  });

  // Click on marker: Show infowindow with articles
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    // Articles posted within a given distance from point clicked will be shown
    var toldist = 2048 / Math.pow(2,map.zoom); //km

    str = '<div id="infowindow_listposts">';

    for(var j=0; j<pos.length; j++){
      if(pos[j] === this.position){
       var optplace = j;
       str += "<h1>
" + Place[j] + "</h1>
<br>";
     }
    }
    str += "<ul>";
    for(var j=0; j<pos.length; j++){
     var dist = calcDistance(pos[j],this.position);

     if(dist < toldist){
      date = new Date(DatePost[j]);
      str += "<li> <h2>
<a href='" + UrlPost[j] + "'>" + TitlePost[j] + "</a> <i>(";
      str += m_names[date.getMonth()] + " " + date.getDate() + ", ";
      str += date.getFullYear() + ") </i></h2>
</li>
";
     }
    }
    str += "</ul>
";
    str += "<i> Articles shown were written less than ";
    if(toldist >= 1)
     str += toldist + "km away from ";
    else
     str += 1000*toldist + "m away from ";
    str += Place[optplace] + ".</i>";

    str += "</div>
";

    if (infowindow){
     infowindow.close();
    }

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content:str
    });

    infowindow.open(map,this);
   });

  markerPos.push(marker);
 }

 // Create the marker of last position
 var lastmarker=new google.maps.Marker({
   position:lastpos,
   clickable:false,
   map:map
 });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>


<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?callback=handleResponse&amp;key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU">
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot for your help! I am currently travelling and it is quite difficult to solve this issue!

Nicolas

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
 <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?callback=handleResponse&amp;key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU">
```

with

```
 <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts/default?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500?callback=handleResponse&amp;key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU">
```

Comment: Thanks Michel but it unfortunately doesn't work. With the command you gave me, there is some authentication issue. I tried to use the following url instead but I still can only fetch the last 10 posts. Any ideas? https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?redirect=false&start-index=1&max-results=500&callback=handleResponse&key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU

Comment: i knew of that error before posting the answer.But i asssumed that perhaps you might have the authority to do so.Are you sure you were logged in while opening the url?

Comment: Hi Michel, apparently the problem is in a limitation with the number of posts I can fetch (20 max for some reasons). If I use this I can increase up to 20 but if I try more it goes back to the default 10 posts... https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?maxResults=20&callback=handleResponse&key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU

I will post a new question to understand this weird limitation. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Here is the link to the new question if you have any suggestion! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184238/limitation-in-the-number-of-posts-to-fetch-with-blogger-api-error-400