# Limitation in the number of posts to fetch with Blogger API (error 400)

Tags: html, rest, google-api, blogger

I am trying to fetch all the post from a blog using the Blogger API. The maximum number of posts to fetch seems to be limited to 20 for some unknown reasons.

If I try this URL:

[https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?maxResults=20&fields=items(title)&key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU](https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?maxResults=20&fields=items%28title%29&key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU)

I get the following response (listing the last 20 post titles as expected):

```
{
"items": [
  {
   "title": "El Caballero"
  },
  {
   "title": "Une traversée de frontière… étonnante!"
  },
  {
   "title": "Hasta luego querida Argentina!"
  },
  {
   "title": "Dernier jour en Argentine"
  },
  {
   "title": "Humahuaca"
  },
  {
   "title": "Purmamarca"
  },
  {
   "title": "Tilcara"
  },
  {
   "title": "Premières grèves"
  },
  {
   "title": "Le Nord Argentin: Salta"
  },
  {
   "title": "Ca en fait de l'eau tout ça..."
  },
  {
   "title": "Un peu de pluie au Brésil"
  },
  {
   "title": "Iguazu"
  },
  {
   "title": "San José"
  },
  {
   "title": "Adieu à Buenos Aires"
  },
  {
   "title": "Traversons en Uruguay"
  },
  {
   "title": "Retour à Buenos Aires"
  },
  {
   "title": "Fin de l'aventure Patagonienne"
  },
  {
   "title": "Les fameuses tours nous surprennent"
  },
  {
   "title": "Un peu de pluie pour se changer les idées"
  },
  {
   "title": "Valle Francés"
  }
 ]
}
```

However, if I increase the maxResults parameters,

[https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?maxResults=21&fields=items(title)&key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU](https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?maxResults=21&fields=items%28title%29&key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU)

I get the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
```

How could I increase the limitation in the maximum number of post that I can fetch?

Thanks,

Nicolas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the API is limited to only pull 20 results as a maximum.

So in order to fetch more than 20 results you have to use the `pageToken` parameter as specified in Bloggers's reference API.

Your first request should include the `nextPageToken` so you will have it in the response. Than use this token to retrieve the next page and so on.

Your first request must be like this :

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?maxResults=20&fields=items%28title%29%2CnextPageToken&key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU

Here is the expected result :

```
{
 "nextPageToken": "CgkIChignPaz5ycQ-rn0pIfipe8q",
 "items": [
  {
   "title": "El Caballero"
  },
  {
   "title": "Une traversée de frontière… étonnante!"
  },
  {
   "title": "Hasta luego querida Argentina!"
  },
  {
   "title": "Dernier jour en Argentine"
  },
  {
   "title": "Humahuaca"
  },
  {
   "title": "Purmamarca"
  },
  {
   "title": "Tilcara"
  },
  {
   "title": "Premières grèves"
  },
  {
   "title": "Le Nord Argentin: Salta"
  },
  {
   "title": "Ca en fait de l'eau tout ça..."
  }
 ]
}
```

Now all you have to do is to pick the `"nextPageToken": "CgkIChignPaz5ycQ-rn0pIfipe8q"` in the result and include it in you next request like this :

https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?%20maxResults=20&pageToken=CgkIChignPaz5ycQ-rn0pIfipe8q&fields=items%28title%29%2CnextPageToken&key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU

The result should show the next 20 posts in addition to a new ``nextPageToken` to use in the next request.

Comment: Great, thanks! Interestingly, when using the nextPageToken parameter, the maxResults parameter seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented what was suggested by Walid Laribi for a travel blog page that retrieve the location of all the posts from the blog and draw the path taken during the travel ([blog](http://el-gato-lindo.blogspot.ch/p/map.html)).

To fetch the location of all the posts, I have first a script that retrieves the first 10 posts and gives me the `nextPageToken`:

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?fields=nextPageToken,items(title,location(name,lat,lng),url,published)&key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU&callback=handleResponse">
```

In the callback of the previous script, we can get the location of each post as well as creating and executing the script to fetch the next posts:

```
// Get latitude/longitude from Blogger
function handleResponse(response) {
 for(i=0; i< response.items.length; i++){
  if(response.items[i].location != undefined){
   Lat.push(response.items[i].location.lat);
   Lng.push(response.items[i].location.lng);
   // etc.
  }
 }

 if(response.nextPageToken != undefined){
  var srctxt = 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/3089072491354463482/posts?fields=nextPageToken,items(title,location(name,lat,lng),url,published)&key=AIzaSyAJO5J-pRCaGOIeRLIJfvAPwxpMLKvwebU&callback=handleResponse&pageToken=' + response.nextPageToken;

  // Execute the new script
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  scriptElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  scriptElement.setAttribute('src', srctxt);
  head.appendChild(scriptElement);
  head.removeChild(scriptElement);
 }
}
```